# Finding the gradient from two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've come across the following question in a text book:

> Find the gradient of the line joining the following pair of points:
> (p+3, q-7), (p+5, 3-q)

So I did the following:

> y2-y1 -> 3-q-q+7 -> 10-2q
>
> x2-x1 -> p+5-p-3 -> 2
>
> (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) -> (10-2q)/2
>
> 2(5-q)/2

And my final result is

> 5-q

Now the book say the answer is -1. Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Your computations look fine to me, maybe it's a mistake in the book or they are asking for something else

Comment: Thanks for that. I suspected it was an error, but couldn't be sure